# Python library to interactively read text file in a command line interface

Tags: library, python, command-line

I’m currently building a little command line interface game in Python (3.7). I would like for the player to be able to read a text file of arbitrary length with some comfort.

The main interaction is done using the `prompt_toolkit` library which is great. At some point, I would like the player to be able to read a text in file, the same way you would read it with `less` for example, page after page, with the possibility to go up and down (or at least just down). Note that I don’t want the mouse (including the wheel) to be used.

I was thinking of coding myself some way to display my files page after pages based on the line count of the terminal, but this seems like there is probably some library for that already that would do that better. Despite my best effort, I didn’t find any.

Any recommendations?